# Indexed objects with symmetry in indices

Tags: python, math, sympy, physics, symbolic-math

I want to implement/calculate in python the following algebraic expression

[the expression](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Csum_%7B%5Csigma&space;%5Cin&space;S_n%7D&space;%5Cprod%5E%7Bn/2%7D_%7Bj=1%7D%5CDelta(%5Csigma_%7B2j-1%7D,&space;%5Csigma_%7B2j%7D))

where [Sn](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?S_n) is the symmetry group of order n (with n an even positive integer) and [Delta](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5CDelta) is a complex function (I will not define this function explicitly in the code, though) that is symmetric in its arguments, i.e.

[condition](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5CDelta(i,j)=%5CDelta(j,i))

With the help of sympy, and studing the sample case n=2, so far I have something like the following:

```
from sympy import *
from itertools import permutations

i, j = symbols('i j', cls=Idx)
Delta = IndexedBase('Delta')

perm = permutations([1, 2])

L = []

for p in list(perm):
    L.append(Delta[p[0], p[1]])

print(sum(L))
```

which yields

```
Delta[1, 2] + Delta[2, 1]
```

> How can I implement the symmetry condition on the indices of the symbol Delta, so that the answer must be  2*Delta[1, 2]?

Comment: Perhaps https://groups.google.com/g/sympy/c/3qhsv5wOg-g/m/7YZqkfYACgAJ?pli=1 ?

Comment: Well, if you're willing to go farther afield, you might consider a different system, which allows one to declare a function or operator as symmetric, so it will handle some of the work for you. (Maybe there is a symmetric or commutative declaration for Sympy, I dunno.) I know Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io) allows one to say `declare(D, symmetric)` and then `D[2, 1]` reduces to `D[1, 2]`. No doubt there are other systems. That might help you avoid reinventing that particular wheel.